# Communication between multi-layered directives in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a few directives that will make up a single "screen" in my app. To create this new screen you would write it like this:

```
<screen title="Test Title">
    <side-menu align="left">
        <menu-item>Test One</menu-item>
        <menu-item selected="true">Test Two</menu-item>
        <menu-item disabled="true">Test Three</menu-item>
    </side-menu>

    <content animation="fade">
        <view>Content for menu option 1</view>
        <view>Content for menu option 2</view>
        <view>Content for menu option 3</view>          
    </content>
</screen>
```

Each `<menu-item>` will display one of the "views" inside of the `<content>` tag. It works like tabs. I've got this set up by keeping track of each `<view>` inside of the `<content>` directive in an array when they are linked. Same for `<menu-item>`.

My question is, now that I've got this set up, what is the best way to communicate between the `<side-menu>` directive and the `<content>` directive to hide and show the correct view when clicked? Should I use events, a common service to hold state, or is there a way I can maybe access the controller inside of the `<screen>` directive from the `<view>` and `<menu-item>` directives, and hold the data/state there? From my understanding I can only access the parent controller from a child directive, but not the "grand parent" controller if you will, unless I use some sort of pass-through.

I plan to have a few more components on this "screen" that will need to communicate as well so I'm hoping to determine the "correct" way to do this before I continue, or at least get some feedback and other ideas.

If any of that is confusing, I'd be happy to provide more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after a bit of digging, I've learned that you can pass an array to the `require` property of a directive.

You can use this to find parent controllers, and grandparent controllers... etc. Previously each of my directives would have one `require` value such as: `require: '^sideMenu'` for the `menuItem` directive.

Now I can require the `sideMenu` and `screen` controllers into the `menuItem` directive by passing an array:

```
require: ['^screen', '^sideMenu']
```

Now in the link function of my `menuItem` directive, I can access these controllers this way:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
    var screenCtrl = controllers[0];
    var sideMenuCtrl = controllers[1];
}
```

Notice the `controllers` property is now an array of the controllers that I required, and are accessed by index. Although I feel as though my directives are little more tightly coupled now, I do like it better than using events/services.

I'm explaining all of this, because no where in the Angular docs does it mention this.